# next/router different based on Dom element clicked?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, event-handling, next-router

I have been developing a darkmode/lightmode hook and system for my platform, using nextjs/react etc.  I have come across a very strange issue where in certain circumstances I get a lightmode flicker when certain dom element types are clicked vs others.  I can try to add more context on how darkmode was implemented however what I find really strange is the fact that assigning the same onClick/onMouseDown event to the same function produces different outcomes.

```
const onClick = (e) => {
    console.log('button clicked')
    router.replace('/dashboard')
}
const onClickPreventDefault = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('button clicked preventDefault')
    router.replace('/dashboard')
}
```

I have created 2 different onClick functions to test which dom elements produce which results, these exist in a react component.

[image: Which Dom Elements produce the bug which do not]

Like I said I could go deeper into the way darkmode was implemented but I actually want to understand why these are producing different results in the first place regardless what those results are.    It does not make sense to me the results I am getting.

Here is a working Demo of the issue and the project, you can see on the login page some buttons cause the flicker some dont.

https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-water-9vkugk

Comment: It may be easier for anyone to help you if you could provide a more complete, comprehensive, and reproducible code example. See [mcve].

Comment: I will work on this, but outside of reproducing the bug, I was hoping someone knew overall why different dom elements "could" have different results.  My assumption would have been calling a function = calling a function you shouldn't have different results based on the type of dom element the function is being called from.  I will spend the rest of the day creating a demo of this problem.

Comment: @DrewReese I have created a codesandbox of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons default to `type="submit"` inside forms, if you want a normal button that does not trigger the submit, the simplest solution is to explicitly set the prop `type="button"` on it.

This "flicker bug" is just the page reloading after the post

Comment: I tried that and it nothing changed for me, its also worth mentioning that in firefox everything flickers even just navigating to pages through the next/link Link component.  I am starting to think firefox may give us a clue to what the real problem is ( maybe ).

Comment: Ah ok, I did not understood what the flicker was, I see now, looks like the context get trashed when the page change